# How to use post build action in a dynamically generated jenkins stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins and I want to add a post-build action to my dynamically generated stages.

I dynamically generate stages by looping over a configuration file I have by doing this:

```
stage('run list'){
  steps {
    script {
      ...
      def stages = stagelist.collectEntries {
        ["${it}": generateStage(it)]
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Where generateStage is defined as:

```
def generateStage(job){
  return {
    stage("${job}"){
      catchError(){
         ....
      }
      post {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which works fine for the stages I have currently. However, when I try to add a post-action to my generate stage function I get NoSuchMethod error.

If I could get some help on this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [static parallel steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) it is possible to use the `post` directive as part of the pipeline syntax, but when you are creating the stages dynamically (in the `generateStage`) you are doing so by using the scripted pipeline syntax which **Does not support the `post` directive**.
What you can do instead is use the scripted pipeline version of the `post` section using the `try` `catch` `finally` syntax to achieve a similar result to that you would achieve using the `post` section in a declarative pipeline.
Try something like:

```
def generateStage(job){
    return {
        stage("${job}"){
            try {
                // Your Execution steps
                ...
                // This is equivalent to the 'success' section in the post directive
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                // This is equivalent to the 'Failure' section in the post directive
            }
            finally {
                // This is equivalent to the 'always' section in the post directive
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not hundred precent equal, as the `try catch` will only detect exception and wont detect direct build result change - but it should work for the majority of steps

Comment: Thanks Noam, I accepted your answer. I honestly wish there was a more pleasing way to write this. It is indeed an issue because this uses the scripted pipeline. For any future people who stumble on this, I have attached a link showing the part of the documentation where this issue is mentioned.  [link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#finishing-up)